# My background worker reports more than 100 percent

Tags: c#

I am writing a program which copies a file. I have the file copying correctly, the progress bar updates, but I get an error which states that the e.ProgressPercentage is at 101. The code for the bgWorker_ProgressChanged event handler is:

```
private void bgWorker_ProgressChanged(object sender, ProgressChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // We will increase the progress bar when work progress is reported.
                    pbCopyProgress.Maximum = 100;
        pbCopyProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;        
    }
```

Here is the code for the bgWorker_DoWork event handler:

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        // Gets the size of the file in bytes.
        Int64 iSize = strInputFile.Length;

        // Keeps track of the total bytes downloaded so we can update the progress bar.
        Int64 iRunningByteTotal = 0;
            // Open the input file for reading.
        using (FileStream InputFile = new FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
        {
            // Using the FileStream object, we can write the output file.
            using (FileStream OutputFile = new FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
            {
                // Loop the stream and get the file into the byte buffer.
                int iByteSize = 0;
                byte[] byteBuffer = new byte[iSize];

                while ((iByteSize = InputFile.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)) > 0)                    
                {
                    // Calculate the progress out of a base "100."
                    double dIndex;
                    double dTotal;
                    double dProgressPercentage;
                    // Write the bytes to the file system at the file path specified.                        
                    dIndex = (double)(iRunningByteTotal);
                    dTotal = (double)byteBuffer.Length;
                    dProgressPercentage = (dIndex / dTotal);
                    OutputFile.Write(byteBuffer, 0, iByteSize);
                    iRunningByteTotal += iByteSize;
                    intProgress = Convert.ToUInt16(dProgressPercentage);
                    // Update the progress bar.
                    bgWorker.ReportProgress(intProgress);

                }                    
                // Close the output file.
                OutputFile.Close();
            }
            // Close the input file.
            InputFile.Close();
        }
    }
```

As I said, the progress bar is updating, but I get an error because it seems to continue copying the file after it has reached 100 percent. If I put in a MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(intProgress)) immediately after the bgWorker.ReportProgress(intProgress) line, the dialog will pop up with 101 for the text. Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 9):

You're dividing your running total by the length of the block buffer, not the whole stream, which means the result is basically unbounded.  You're failing to multiply by 100 too, but that problem is masked by the fact that the ratio is growing larger than one.

But you're making it all look very difficult - the code you want is simply:

```
 bgWorker.ReportProgress((int)(100 * runningByteTotal / fileLength))
```

You should set up fileLength before the start of the loop (and it needs to be the length of the file, not the filename, as @azyberezovsky points out in his answer).

You can allow this calculation to happen with simple integer arithmetic rather than needing floating point types, as long as the multiply by 100 happens before the divide.

As a stylistic point, you don't need all the 'i's and 'd's in front of variable names - that's not considered to be good C# style.   Nor are variables normally started with a capital letter - if nothing else, that confuses the SO code syntax highlighter...

Comment: I copied some code from an answer to another question and it had the i's and d's in it. Your answer helped me fix another issue I was having and was going to post a question on here about it, however, it did not fix the question asked here. If I put in your code, it multiplies the percentage by 100 (the progress bar throws an error saying that the value of the progress bar is at 200).

Comment: You need to stop copying code and start thinking about how it works - if the formula 100*progress/totalSize is not giving you a percentage 0-100, then either progress or totalSize are wrong - you should work out which using the debugger if you can't see it in the code.

Answer (score 1):

That is not size of file - it is simply length of file name string:

```
Int64 iSize = strInputFile.Length;
```

And this is also not file size, this is a size of buffer you use to write data to output file:

```
dTotal = (double)byteBuffer.Length;
```

What you need is

```
private void bgWorker_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
{
    using (FileStream inputFile = new FileStream(strInputFile, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read, FileShare.None))
    using (FileStream outputFile = new FileStream(strOutputFile, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write, FileShare.None))
    {
        long totalBytesToWrite = inputFile.Length;
        long totalBytesWritten = 0;       
        byte[] buffer = new byte[512]; // provide any buffer size here
        int bytesToWrite;
        ushort percentage;

        while ((bytesToWrite = inputFile.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
        {
            outputFile.Write(buffer, 0, bytesToWrite);
            totalBytesWritten += bytesToWrite;
            percentage = (ushort)((100 * totalBytesWritten)/totalBytesToWrite);
            bgWorker.ReportProgress(percentage);
        }
    }
}
```

Keep in mind - you don't need to close stream manually if you are using `using` block - stream will be disposed (i.e. closed) at the end of this block.

Answer (score 0):

Declare maximum value of:

```
pbCopyProgress.Maximum = InputFile.Read(byteBuffer, 0, byteBuffer.Length)
```

Remove line:

```
percentage = (ushort)((100 * totalBytesWritten)/totalBytesToWrite);
```

from `bgWorker_DoWork`, and declare counter before while cycle in `bgWorker_DoWork`. For example:

```
int counter = 1;
```

before the closing brace of while increment the counter (`counter++`);
in `bgWorker_ProgressChanged` update the percentage:

```
pbCopyProgress.Value = e.ProgressPercentage;
```

If you want to fill any label with text showing the percentage the following line calculates the percentage:

```
int percent = 100 / (byteBuffer.Length / e.ProgressPercentage);
Label1.Text = String.Format("Passed: {0} %, percent.ToString());
```

Those lines should be also in `bgWorker_ProgressChanged`.